# Creating PayPal buy now button with multiple products (java sdk)

Tags: java, paypal

I am having difficulty creating a PayPal "Buy Now" button with the Java paypal-sdk. Single products seem to work okay. I would like the button to go to the checkout page with the product prices, descriptions and item numbers and NOT be editable. Here is a look at my code. First I create my array of button vars. (This code snipped is in Groovy)

```
List<String> buttonVarList = new ArrayList<String>()    
int count = 1
int size = priceMap.size()
double totalPrice = 0.0

for (Map.Entry<String, PriceInfo> entry : priceMap.entrySet()) 
{
    String skuKey = entry.getKey()
    PriceInfo priceInfo = entry.getValue()

    String itemNum = (size > 1) ? "_" + String.valueOf(count) + "=" : "="
    Product product = Product.findByProductCode(skuKey)
    buttonVarList.add("item_name" + itemNum + product.productName)
    buttonVarList.add("item_number" + itemNum + skuKey)
    buttonVarList.add("amount" + itemNum + priceInfo.unitPrice)
    buttonVarList.add("quantity" + itemNum + priceInfo.qty)
    totalPrice += priceInfo.totalPrice
    count++
}

buttonVarList.add("currency_code=" + currency)
buttonVarList.add("business=" + grailsApplication.config.grails.paypal.email)
buttonVarList.add("subtotal=" + totalPrice)
buttonVarList.add("notify_url=" + grailsApplication.config.grails.paypal.notifyPaypal)
buttonVarList.add("return=" + grailsApplication.config.grails.paypal.successPaypal)
buttonVarList.add("cancel_return=" + grailsApplication.config.grails.paypal.cancelPaypal)
Payment payment = createTransaction(null, priceMap, request.getRemoteAddr(), "PAYPAL")
buttonVarList.add("transactionId=" + payment.transactionId)
buttonVarList.add("buyerId=" + payment.buyerId)
return paypalApi.createButton(buttonVarList)
```

After I create the button var list, I create my encrypted button.

```
BMCreateButtonRequestType requestType = new BMCreateButtonRequestType();
requestType.setButtonType(ButtonTypeType.fromValue("BUYNOW"));
requestType.setButtonCode(ButtonCodeType.fromValue("ENCRYPTED"));
requestType.setButtonLanguage("en");
requestType.setButtonVar(buttonVarList);
```

With BUYNOW as the button type, the button will work for single products, but for multiple products (item_name_1, item_name_2 variables etc), it seems to not recognize the products and the checkout page has the price and description editable. From the documentation I can see this is likely because it does not recognize the additional products "If this variable is omitted, buyers see a field in which they can enter the item name."

I have also tried using the CART button type, which works for single products, but for multiple products returns the error 11929 "A cart button must have an item name and amount specified."

Is this the correct way to specify multiple products in the checkout cart? I feel like I must be missing something simple. Thanks for the help.

EDIT 1:

I have tried adding the cart upload option "upload=1" with an unencrypted cart button. If I then remove the underscores from the item button vars in code, then re-add them by hand to the generated button (and remove add=1 which upload does not seem to override..) it seems to work. I obviously can't do this since I need encrypted buttons..but at least I can see there is a way to get it work. Perhaps I should ditch the Paypal Java Button Manager API?

Comment: Do you intentionally not have semicolons in the first code snippet? Cause java without semicolons will cause you problems...

Comment: Sorry, this is in a Grails applications, so that first code snipped is in Groovy. The second snipped is in Java using the java paypal-sdk

Comment: I am not familier with your Question but you can find something here.. http://dreamix.eu/blog/java/integration-with-paypal-java-sdk

Answer (score 0):

This API looks to be very confusingly documented, but I think the PayPal BuyNow buttons, regardless of how you generate them, are intended for single item purchases - that's their entire point:

https://www.paypal.com/bm/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside

Even with an add to cart button - the intent is still that it is a single item you are adding to the cart:

https://www.paypal.com/bm/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_shoppingcart-intro-outside

You'd then go to your cart and complete purchase there - but both add to cart and buy now look to me to be designed for single items.  Once you get to the cart - then you are dealing with multiple items.

Comment: You can add multiple products using the cart upload command. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/ This is what we use on our live site when we create the form by hand. The issue is the java paypal sdk seems to ignore the cart upload parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible , but you can always create a [Buttons for single purchases](https://www.paypal.com/md/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside)  for a pack of all your multiple product that are eligible for one checkout

But still the best and flexible solution is to use [Buttons for shopping cart purchases](https://www.paypal.com/md/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_shoppingcart-intro-outside)